# How to efficiently rename file names using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to rename files based on a `;;;` separated values.

example list is

```
name1;;;name_1
name2;;;name_2
name3;;;name_3
```

And in the directory I have files such as `name_1.txt`, `name_2.txt` and so on.

below is my code.

```
import os
import sys

#Usage: python rename.py rename.lst directory

r_lst = sys.argv[1]
directory = sys.argv[2]

with open(r_lst) as rfile:
    remove_list = rfile.readlines()

remove_list = [x.strip() for x in remove_list]

for item in remove_list:
    A_Column = item.split(";;;")[0]
    B_Column = item.split(";;;")[1]

    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        basename = filename.split(".")[0]
        if basename == B_Column:
            new_name = A_Column + "." + filename.split(".")[1]
            os.rename(directory+filename, directory+new_name)
```

My code works on renaming the files to their correct names. However, how do I make this program more efficient? It iterates over the `remove_list` then within that iteration it also iterates over files in the directory.

Can I make this program more efficient?

Comment: Review of working code is off-topic for SO so that's likely why.  See https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going through each file in the directory, you could use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) with `B_Column+".*"` to get only those that you're interested in.

```
import glob
filesmatchingpattern = glob.glob(B_Column+".*")
```

Also note that your code may misbehave for multi-dotted file names such as `name1.file.txt`, which IMHO will become `name_1.file` instead of `name_1.file.txt`.

Comment: i think the key piece of work that's being repeated multiple times is that for each entry in `remote_list` the directory gets listed and file names checked. Ideally that'd just be a single pass. The current solution is O(m*n) but should be able to be more like O(m+n).